# How to avoid emerge recalculating dependencies after adding required keywords/uses?

Tags: gentoo, dependencies, emerge, funtoo

While `emerge --autounmask-writes` followed by a `etc-update` basically automates adding additional keywords and use flags, running `emerge` afterwards (without any other modifications) will *again* calculate the very same dependencies, which on a slower machine may waste several redundant minutes - how can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as far as I know and it's not sane because they are very much different.

`--autounmask-write` will just help you with configs editing. But after editing your configs you also can do anything like `sync` or maybe adding some 3d party overlays, noone can knows and as usual portage will need to check deps again.

Comment: Sure, the point is I'd like to have `emerge` do all that in one step, i.e. do the `--autounmask-write`, the `etc-update` and then directly use the cached dependencies without ever returning to the prompt. Of course a parallel `sync` should indeed be blocked for that...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I don't know automatic method for it currently.